# How to use Android to simulator with Apportable

Tags: apportable

I have just installed Apportable and tried it out. I am trying to read the documentation but can't find any explanation how to start up generated code in Android SDK simulator? ...or is a device required for initial tests?

Could someone point me at the right direction please?

Comment: You're question is better worded, but the same answer is available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971792/can-you-install-an-android-device-simulator-in-xcode-when-using-apportable

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used apportable (looks like a new project for the weekend), but according to their docs (http://docs.apportable.com/cli.html#common-build-commands), if you run `apportable build` it will generate an APK file---the packaged application that gets installed on the device or emulator.

You can install the APK on the emulator using `adb`, a command line tool that is part of the Android SDK. So, first, install the Android SDK if you haven't already. Then, assuming your APK file is named *sample.apk*, run `adb install sample.apk`, and the app will be installed in your emulator.