# Segmentation fault when running iOS app on Android emulator using Apportable

Tags: ios, iphone, gdb, segmentation-fault, apportable

I am trying to run an iOS app on an Android emulator using `Apportable`

I compile and run the app using the following command in Terminal

```
ROOTED=yes MTP=no apportable debug
```

The emulator is setup with these settings:

[Can you install an Android Device Simulator in xcode when using Apportable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971792/can-you-install-an-android-device-simulator-in-xcode-when-using-apportable)

It compiles fine, but i get a `SIGSEGV` Segmentation Fault when the app is on the splash screen in the emulator. When i try to get a trace with `bt` it doesn't show anything.

I have tried Googling for solutions on how to get a trace for the error but without luck.

Here is the output from the `Terminal`:

```
Debugging...
1871 KB/s (26836917 bytes in 14.005s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Chaser-debug.apk
Success
Starting: Intent { cmp=Cromian.CHASER/com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity (has extras) }

Failed to load one the Breakpoints files:
/Users/Anders/Documents/Xcode/iOS_code/Cromian/Chaser/chaser_app/Chaser.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/Anders.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints.xcbkptlist
/Users/Anders/Documents/Xcode/iOS_code/Cromian/Chaser/chaser_app/Chaser.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/Anders.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist

Attaching to pid 1149
Attached; pid = 1149
Listening on port 5039
657 KB/s (9592 bytes in 0.014s)
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5-https://github.com/apportable/gdb Jan  3 2014 13:47:56
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0 --target=arm-elf-linux".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for gralloc.goldfish.so.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
libthread_db:td_ta_new: Probing system for platform bug.
libthread_db:td_ta_new: Running as root, nothing to do.
0x40037ebc in epoll_wait ()
   from /Users/Anders/.apportable/cache/devices/emulator-5554/libs/libc.so
$1 = 1
$2 = 0
Breakpoint 1 at 0x5cadf2c8: file /Users/Anders/Documents/Xcode/iOS_code/Cromian/Chaser/chaser_app/Chaser/main.m, line 13.
Breakpoint 2 at 0x5a1d8ed0
[New Thread 1169]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 1169]
0x40005a1e in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x40005a1e in ?? ()
#1  0x400044d2 in ?? ()
#2  0x400044d2 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

How do i find the cause for the segmentation fault?

EDIT:
By using the command x/200a $sp i was able to get the following trace, after the segmentation fault:

```
(gdb) x/200a $sp
0x57b7fac0: 0x0 0x0 0x57b7fbe0  0xcb18276c
0x57b7fad0: 0x0 0x0 0x40015964  0x40015a88
0x57b7fae0: 0x40015bac  0x40015cd0  0x40010bd4  0x40011064
0x57b7faf0: 0x40011188  0x400100ac  0x40010cf8  0x40010e1c
0x57b7fb00: 0x40010f40  0x0 0x28    0x0
0x57b7fb10: 0xcb18276c  0xcb18276c  0xcb18276c  0x3f000000
0x57b7fb20: 0x0 0xffffffd1  0x2d0   0x0
0x57b7fb30: 0x4045adcc  0x2a19da10  0x2a187260  0x4045fcb0
0x57b7fb40: 0x404584b8  0x1 0x57b80c6c  0x4003ecbb <snprintf+79>
0x57b7fb50: 0x0 0x0 0x400174c4  0x580ce000
0x57b7fb60: 0x580ce034  0x40003ff9  0x400175c0  0x57b7fc07
0x57b7fb70: 0x0 0xfdc   0xffff0208  0x57b7fbe4
0x57b7fb80: 0xfff   0x26    0x57b7fba8  0x400174c4
0x57b7fb90: 0x0 0x57b7fbe4  0x2a187260  0x4045fcb0
0x57b7fba0: 0x404584b8  0x40003f4b  0x57b7fbe4  0x4000
0x57b7fbb0: 0x3c14001   0x3c10000   0x57b7fbe4  0x4045adcc
0x57b7fbc0: 0x2a19da10  0x400050bf  0x0 0x4044758f
0x57b7fbd0: 0x2a187260  0x5a8ff01c <__CFStrAllocateMutableContents+80>  0x584d1040  0x4006b228 <__stack_chk_guard>
0x57b7fbe0: 0x30025 0x7379732f  0x2f6d6574  0x2f62696c
0x57b7fbf0: 0x2f6c6765  0x4562696c  0x655f4c47  0x616c756d
0x57b7fc00: 0x6e6f6974  0x6f732e    0x0 0x0
0x57b7fc10: 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0x57b7fc20: 0x0 0x20    0x5a86695c <__CFAllocatorSystemAllocate>    0x0
0x57b7fc30: 0x57b7fd08  0x1 0x0 0x5844f640 <arena_malloc+1020>
0x57b7fc40: 0x5b04ae00  0x0 0x1728  0x12
0x57b7fc50: 0x0 0x10    0x20    0x1
0x57b7fc60: 0x57b7fc80  0x58449d48 <__wrap_malloc+240>  0x57b7fc78  0x20
0x57b7fc70: 0x600   0x5d1b9461  0x1 0x5d1b9440
0x57b7fc80: 0x5d1b9460  0x0 0x5d1b9460  0x0
0x57b7fc90: 0x0 0x14    0xcb18276c  0x20
0x57b7fca0: 0x12    0x2 0x57b7fd80  0x1
0x57b7fcb0: 0xa 0x0 0x5a9d2270 <_MergedGlobals+112> 0x7
0x57b7fcc0: 0x0 0x5d1b9581  0xcb18276c  0x5d1b9560
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
0x57b7fcd0: 0x5d1b9580  0x0 0x5d1b9580  0x0
0x57b7fce0: 0x0 0x3 0x0 0x20
0x57b7fcf0: 0x2 0x1 0x57b7fdd0  0x1
0x57b7fd00: 0xa 0x0 0x5a9d2270 <_MergedGlobals+112> 0x57b7fe08
0x57b7fd10: 0x2c78  0x0 0x0 0x57b7fd20
0x57b7fd20: 0x200078c   0x5a1b6860 <OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32+76>    0x5a86695c <__CFAllocatorSystemAllocate>    0x6325
0x57b7fd30: 0x584d11a8  0x7fffffff  0xa 0x4004471b <strtol+163>
0x57b7fd40: 0x5d1b9584  0x57b7fd94  0xa 0x5d1b9583
0x57b7fd50: 0x5d1b9584  0x1 0x5d1a67e0  0x1
0x57b7fd60: 0x584d10d0  0x88    0x5d1a67e0  0x5844f65c <arena_malloc+1048>
0x57b7fd70: 0x584d11a8  0x1 0x584d1040  0x1728
0x57b7fd80: 0x5d1b95e0  0x0 0x584d1358  0x584d1040
0x57b7fd90: 0x0 0x5844f640 <arena_malloc+1020>  0x5d1b3cc4  0x0
0x57b7fda0: 0x1728  0x7c    0x584d1040  0x5a2e64dc <_atomic_lock>
0x57b7fdb0: 0x20348 0x5b00f660  0x584d1040  0x80860000
0x57b7fdc0: 0x20348 0x5b00f660  0x80860000  0x5a1b6860 <OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32+76>
0x57b7fdd0: 0x5cc3a164 <OBJC_CLASS_$_VerdeActivity> 0x5b04ae00  0x5cc3a164 <OBJC_CLASS_$_VerdeActivity> 0x1e
```

Comment: Lack of backtrace often indicates a GL driver crash. Not sure about on the simulator.  Also you can try x/200a $sp to find some likely symbols for up the call tree.

Comment: I am not using GL in my app. Okay i will try that command

Comment: I updated the question with the trace i received using the command `x/200a $sp`

Comment: Paul, can you see what is wrong by looking at the trace?

Comment: No, it looks deep in memory allocation. Maybe you'll find something if you look even further up the call stack. Otherwise, you're stuck with binary searching and debugger stepping.

Comment: i don't recommend use of android emulators for debugging

Comment: Did you find a solution here? My first try at apportable is showing the same failure signature.

Answer (score 0):

I tried porting latest cocos2d game from iTerm to android emulator using apportable. I successfully loaded and tested my game on android emulator. This is great achievement for me as I would not be buying new devices to test out my app in android devices. So, here is the solution.

After some research, I found that the segmentation fault occurred due to lack of OpenGLES driver path by the emulator. While initializing emulator (added via AVD Manager) from terminal, if the OpenGL path is not found correctly, the terminal will show error in console as follows:

```
emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: dlopen(libOpenglRender.dylib, 1): image not found
```

```
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
```

So if you don't fix this issue the segmentation fault will occur for sure. To fix this issue you will need to Export your lib path of android sdk tools. Check [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/gwcLeOTfxD4/kW-qebk0C-wJ) for details.

Once you fixed openGLES driver path. You can use **"apportable load"** command to load your game to android emulator. Note that the "apportable debug" (with flags) didn't worked for me. I think it is because only device would support to debug loading not emulator. I added few emulators and tried on them as well and the result was fine.

NOTE: I am using Macbook pro Retina with 16 GB ram. The loading of emulator can be bit slow as it takes lot of RAM and processing.

Happy porting and all the best.

Comment: I am not using OpenGL but only UIKit