# How can I install ARM v7a System Image on Mac?

Tags: android, ios, macos, android-emulator, apportable

I am trying to run an android emulator on my Mac to test Apportable using a virtual machine. I followed the accepted solution in [Can you install an Android Device Simulator in xcode when using Apportable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971792/can-you-install-an-android-device-simulator-in-xcode-when-using-apportable) . How can I install  ARM EABI v7a System Image on Mac since I don't think it's installed from the image below and I don't see any options to install it.

[image]